# Use LAG with a specific condition on what LAG value to take?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, sql-server-2016

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
Row     Volume
1       10000
2       8000
3       0.01
4       0
5       5000
6       0
```

Now, if I were to use the `LAG()` function in SQL Server, I believe the following table will result:

```
Row     Volume     LAG(Volume)
1       10000      NULL
2       8000       10000
3       0.01       8000
4       0          0.01
5       5000       0
6       0          5000
```

However, this is not exactly what I am looking for, so allow me to provide some background as to why I need the `LAG(Volume)` column. The reason for it is because small values, such as `0.01` or `0` in my example, are likely to be data processing errors, so I want to override them with the last non-`0.01` or non-`0` value and then update the table by a `JOIN`. I believe this requires me to first come up with the `LAG(Volume)` column, but I would need the `LAG()` function to ignore some values. In my example, they would be `0.01` and `0`. I guess, one could also say that I would like the lagged value to depend on what the lagged value actually is. In other words, for my example, I would like the following table to be produced instead:

```
Row     Volume     LAG(Volume)
1       10000      NULL
2       8000       10000
3       0.01       8000
4       0          8000
5       5000       8000
6       0          5000
```

Note that, for Row 6, the lag should be 5000 (and not 8000) as, although its volume is 0, its lag is neither 0 nor 0.01.

Can this be done?

Perhaps if anyone has alternatives as to how I can update these values to the last non-`0.01` or non-`0` value without having to create an intermediate lag column, please let me know as well.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a parameter called OFFSET in LAG function which can be used to achieve this result. This parameter can be a column, subquery, or other expression that evaluates to a positive integer.

Comment: @Madhukar Hello! Would you be able to elaborate what you are suggesting in an answer?

Comment: May be using something like this. Please note that this is just an example and not the answer - LAG(volume, CASE WHEN volume IN (0.01,0) then 2 else 1 end) over (order by row)

Comment: @Madhukar - but there can be an arbitrary length sequence of rows to ignore - e.g. if preceding 10 have `volume IN (0.01,0)` then offset needs to be 11 - how can that `11` be calculated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On earlier versions you can use a concatenation approach to simulate `IGNORE NULLS`. [2016 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wVJ4OxHQ).

It uses `MAX` with a window of `ORDER BY [Row] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

Assuming `Row` is a positive integer the value going into the `MAX` is a concatenation of `Row` and `Volume` constructed such that later `Row` numbers will be the `MAX` - but these are nulled out in the cases that you want to ignore and `MAX` automatically disregards those.

The `Volume` is then extracted out with `SUBSTRING` and `CAST` back to `decimal` - if you are not in fact using `decimal(12,2)` then change this to what you *are* using.

```
SELECT 
 *,
 CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', [Row]),10) + CASE WHEN Volume > 0.01 THEN CAST(Volume AS VARCHAR(20)) END) OVER (ORDER BY [Row] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 11, 20) AS decimal(12,2))
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* you're on the latest version of SQL Server (as there's no mention you're not) you could use a `CASE` expression to `NULL` values lower than *n* (I assume `1`) and then tell `LAG` to `IGNORE NULLS`:

```sql
LAG (CASE WHEN Volume > 1 THEN Volume END) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY [Row]) AS LagVolumn
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rhSsjFeA)

<sup>It appears the OP is on 2016, not 2022. I am leaving this here anyway, as it may be useful to others in the future.</sup>

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! Your query works when I exclude the `IGNORE NULLS` part. When I include it, SQL Server throws me an error - "The function 'LAG' must have an OVER clause." Is this because my SQL Server version is not the latest? I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1.

Comment: This is why I stated *"Assuming you're on the latest version of SQL Server"* @EthanMark . The version of SSMS is irrelevant to that. SSMS 17 supported SQL Server 2008-2017.

Comment: My apologies. This is probably a stupid question, but how do I check what version of SQL Server am I on?

Comment: `PRINT @@VERSION` would be one way.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. The output says that I am on SQL Server 2016. Is that a problem?

Comment: It's not the latest version, so it won't support `IGNORE NULLS`, @EthanMark . Only  2022+ has `IGNORE NULL`s. You won't be able to achieve what you want with `LAG` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to implement your logic with a correlation in a sub-query:

```
select *, (
  select top (1) volume from t t2 
  where t2.[row] < t.[row] and t2.volume > 1
  order by [row] desc
) as Lag_Volume
from t
order by Id;
```